# Instantiating a delegate method to be used in a class library

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, class-library

I'm building an email-monitoring framework that I'll be using for a handful of users, so I'm building a class library to wrap everything in. I'm instantiating the configuration (sender, subject, last-received, ...) in a static class. Therefore, I have something like this.

```
public static class MyConfig 
{
     public static int Sender { get; set; }
     // and so on and so forth

     public static void BuildMyConfig(string theSender, string theRecipient, ...) 
     {
         Sender = theSender;
         // yada yada yada...
     }
}

public class Monitoring 
{
    public delegate void DoSomethingWithEmail(EmailContents theContents);

    public void StartMonitoring() {

       //When I get an email, I call the method
       DoSomethingWithEmail(theEmailWeJustGot);
    }
}
```

Obviously, what we do with the email will be something completely different in each case. What I'm trying to is instantiate that delegate. Where would I do that? The MyConfig class and then invoke it from there as a static method? The instance of the Monitoring class?

An application would look like...

```
public class SpecificMonitor 
{
    Monitoring.BuildMyConfig("foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com", ...);

    Monitoring m = new Monitoring();
    m.StartMonitoring();

    //But where do I build the delegate method???

}
```

I've gotten compiling errors with every option I've tried so far. I've also tried overriding a method instead of using a delegate, using interfaces... but I think delegation is where it's at.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent with the rest of your design (although I do not necessarily agree that the design is great) you could allow for the *callback* to be set in the configuration class

```
public static class MyConfig
{
    public static string Sender { get; set; }
    public static DoSomethingWithEmail EmailReceivedCallback { get; set; }

    public static void BuildMyConfig(string theSender, string theRecipient,
            DoSomethingWithEmail callback)
    {
        Sender = theSender;
        EmailReceivedCallback = callback;
    }
}

//  Make sure you bring the delegate outside of the Monitoring class!
public delegate void DoSomethingWithEmail(string theContents);
```

When an incoming email is acknowledged by your application you can now pass the email to the callback assigned to the configuration class

```
public class Monitoring
{
    public void StartMonitoring()
    {
        const string receivedEmail = "New Answer on your SO Question!";

        //Invoke the callback assigned to the config class
        MyConfig.EmailReceivedCallback(receivedEmail);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of usage

```
static void Main()
{
    MyConfig.BuildMyConfig("...", "...", HandleEmail);

    var monitoring = new Monitoring();
    monitoring.StartMonitoring();
}

static void HandleEmail(string thecontents)
{
    // Sample implementation
    Console.WriteLine("Received Email: {0}",thecontents);
}
```

Comment: Hey! It looks like that will compile just fine. Will put it through its paces soon. So, basically, the delegate is housed in the monitoring class but I can instantiate it through another class. Nice! Out of curiosity, though... what issue do you have with the design? Just trying to improve, that's all, so by all means, be frank. :)

Comment: I am sure that an object-orientated approach (think polymorphism) would be more suitable this purpose.

Comment: So, basically, you're suggesting overriding the DoSomethingWithEmail method when instantiating the Monitoring class? That's actually how I actually started, trying to do that, but I couldn't override a static method inside of the Monitoring class.

Comment: Yeah basically. Maybe something like this [_this_](https://gist.github.com/ByteBlast/7074685).

Comment: Oh, I see how you're instantiating it now. Haven't played much with abstract classes, but this looks very promising. Worth poking around with — because inheritance was what I wanted to do in the first place. Thanks for the snippet!

Comment: — A quick update: I actually ended up using your snippet from above, because I needed to use the callback as a static method inside of a notification callback from the Exchange API, so setting the abstract method as static was a no-no. But the other one has been bookmarked — a very nice and scalable solution. The example above did the trick, so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Define the constructor so that when people instantiate a `Monitoring` object, they must define the delegate:

```
public class Monitoring 
{
    public delegate void DoSomethingWithEmail(EmailContents theContents);

    public Monitoring(Delegate DoSomethingWithEmail)
    {
        this.DoSomethingWithEmail = DoSomethingWithEmail;
    }

    public void StartMonitoring() {

       //When I get an email, I call the method
       DoSomethingWithEmail(theEmailWeJustGot);
    }
}
```

Then pass in the `delegate` you want when you instantiate each `Monitoring`:

```
Monitoring m = new Monitoring(delegate(EmailContents theContents) 
{ 
    /* Do stuff with theContents here */
});
m.StartMonitoring();
```

Comment: Thanks! Between your answer and the one above, it looks like I'll have options. Let me compare the different options and see what shakes out. Thanks again!